# Run Powershell script on machine start?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a script that I need to have run every time a certain Windows XP machine boots up.  I've written it in Powershell, and it works.  But how do I get it to run when the machine starts?  Not when I log in, but on machine start.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the edit Jared.  I was in such as hurry to fix this before the long weekend!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Task Scheduler - Run at Startup

Answer (score 3):

add a new key to the following registry hive.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

if you want the program be executed once only then add it to 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
keys in this hive will be deleted after it is executed. You can add ! at the beginning of the name to force the deletion to happen at the end of the execution.

The sequence of execution is listed in the following link
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179365